# zsh: locking failed for ~/.cache/zsh/zsh_history: file exists

Tags: zsh, command-history, lock

I have a bind mount `~/.cache/zsh` folder between multiple hosts with `rw` and `defaults` when doing mount.

When I start both machine and zsh trying to lock `zsh_history`, it gives error `zsh: locking failed for ~/.cache/zsh/zsh_history: file exists` on one of a machine.

Google but seems no one got this kind mesg before, when and why zsh give this kind of mesg? How to make it happy?

Answer (score 0):

zsh is creating `.zsh_history.LOCK` in the same directory `.zsh_history` exists, so you need write perms to be able to create lock file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by hard shutdown or terminal crashing, so you need to delete lock file `.zsh_history.LOCK`, placed in the same directory and restart your terminal.